# Why React function do not retuning div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am not getting div in my dom. there is div with id of teams when I inspect app in browser and function returning both console.logs but no divs inside #teams div. :S

```
const Teams = () => {
  const homeTeam = [
    { position: 0, team: "home", visible: true, x: "30%", y: "30%" },
    { position: 1, team: "home", visible: true, x: "40%", y: "30%" },
  ];

  const awayTeam = [
    { position: 0, team: "away", visible: true, x: "70%", y: "70%" },
    { position: 1, team: "away", visible: true, x: "60%", y: "70%" },
  ];

  const setTeams = (home, away) => {
    const setPlayers = (team) => {
      team.map((player, index) => {
        console.log(player);
        return (
          <div className={`player ${player.team === "home" ? "home" : "away"}`} key={index}>
            {player.position === 0 ? "G" : null}
          </div>
        );
      });
    };

    setPlayers(home);
    setPlayers(away);
  };

  return <div id="teams">{setTeams(homeTeam, awayTeam)}</div>;
};

export default Teams;
```

Comment: `team.map(` you need `return team.map(`

Comment: I also needed `return [setPlayers(home), setPlayers(away)];` in order to work

Comment: @Klak031 why do you need to return an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```
const Teams = () => {
  const [homeTeam] = useState([
    { position: 0, team: 'home', visible: true, x: '30%', y: '30%' },
    { position: 1, team: 'home', visible: true, x: '40%', y: '30%' }
  ]);

  const [awayTeam] = useState([
    { position: 0, team: 'away', visible: true, x: '70%', y: '70%' },
    { position: 1, team: 'away', visible: true, x: '60%', y: '70%' }
  ]);

  const setPlayers = useCallback(
    (team) =>
      team.map((player, index) => (
        <div className={`player ${player.team === 'home' ? 'home' : 'away'}`} key={index}>
          {player.position === 0 ? 'G' : null}
        </div>
      )),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {setPlayers(homeTeam)}
      {setPlayers(awayTeam)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Teams;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything in your `setPlayers` and `setTeams` functions. You need to return `team.map` and `setPlayers` as well like so:

```
const setTeams = (home, away) => {
    return setPlayers = (team) => {
      return team.map((player, index) => {
        console.log(player);
        return (
          <div className={`player ${player.team === "home" ? "home" : "away"}`} key={index}>
            {player.position === 0 ? "G" : null}
          </div>
        );
      });
    };
```

Comment: This is insufficient, also needs to return something from the `setTeams` function

Comment: @Lennholm what else do you need to return? A function can return only one value.

Comment: @VinaySharma The function `setTeams` also needs to return something. As it stands, it only makes two calls to the `setPlayers` function but doesn't do anything with the results of those calls and doesn't return anything, which means that the call `setTeams(homeTeam, awayTeam)` results in `undefined`.

Comment: @Lennholm what do you mean it needs to return **something**? Please don't use vague words and specify the exact details.

Comment: @VinaySharma Something, as opposed to nothing. People need to do some thinking of their own, not expect to be given code patches for free. I explained a problem with the code and why it won't work as expected. Since the exact solution depends on exactly what result the OP wants, the rest will be up to him to figure out, which he did and wrote a comment about (that you questioned for some reason).

Comment: @Lennholm good spot! Totally overlooked that one too. Edited the answer.

Comment: @Lennholm okay I understand that, btw where did OP write the comment? I want to read that.

Comment: @VinaySharma Below the question, where OP described that they needed to return the results of the two `setPlayers` calls in an array.

Comment: I feel he's trying to apply a concept of his own, not support by React otherwise. Therefore all the answers are pointing to the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

setPlayers and setTeams function does not return anything. Hence you do not see those element. Do this instead.

```
const Teams = () => {
    const homeTeam = [
      { position: 0, team: "home", visible: true, x: "30%", y: "30%" },
      { position: 1, team: "home", visible: true, x: "40%", y: "30%" },
    ];
  
    const awayTeam = [
      { position: 0, team: "away", visible: true, x: "70%", y: "70%" },
      { position: 1, team: "away", visible: true, x: "60%", y: "70%" },
    ];
  
    const setTeams = (home, away) => {
        const team = [...home,...away];
        return team.map((player, index)=>
        <div className={`player ${player.team === "home" ? "home" : "away"}`} key={index}>
            {player.position === 0 ? "G" : null}
          </div>
        );
    };
  
    return <div id="teams">{setTeams(homeTeam, awayTeam)}</div>;
  };
  
  export default Teams;
```

Answer (score 1):

Main Issue is when you are using your two functions :

```
 setPlayers(home);
 setPlayers(away);
```

within your `setPlayers` function. The returned map template (JSX) is actually returned to the respective calling function which is setPlayers() function (calling two times with different arguments). And here the execution of your program basically ends. No JSX is returned to main component's `return()` method.

To make sure the the JSX is returned with proper mapped JSX,  JSX needs to return to the `setTeams(homeTeam, awayTeam)` so that it is rendered in our app. I have made sure I use one function `setTeams` twice in the code with two arrays `homeTeam` and `awayTeam`

You shoudl try this code instead :)

```js
const App = () => {
  const homeTeam = [
    { position: 0, team: "home", visible: true, x: "30%", y: "30%" },
    { position: 1, team: "home", visible: true, x: "40%", y: "30%" }
  ];

  const awayTeam = [
    { position: 0, team: "away", visible: true, x: "70%", y: "70%" },
    { position: 1, team: "away", visible: true, x: "60%", y: "70%" }
  ];

  const setTeams = (team) => {
    return team.map((player, index) => (
      <div
        className={`player ${player.team === "home" ? "home" : "away"}`}
        key={index}
      >
        {player.position === 0 ? "G" : null}
      </div>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div id="teams">
      <h1>My APP</h1>
      {setTeams(homeTeam)}

      {setTeams(awayTeam)}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```